# Upload raw code on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem: I built a website with only raw code, and now I want to switch to a content management system like wordpress. I’d like to know how can I just upload all my code (html, css and javascript) without screwing up with the code on wordpress especially with php. Maybe do I need to find a blank theme, and for blank I mean a blank page. Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of PHP like `php_include` and such and how it works to integrate WordPress to your site. You will also need to familiarise yourself with how WordPress works (functions, hooks, widgets, etc). I would recommend customising a pre-made WP Theme like the Twenty Sixteen theme and get yourself familiar with the system. You can also refer to the official WordPress Documentation here to help you through the learning process: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Removed unnecessary tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you have. You should start with blank template and do part of the job, other part is to fill the content - it is possible to put there php by some plugins but it is not secure.
here you have template:
http://html5blank.com

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I know both php and mysql. My problem is that when I try to install any of the basic theme on wordpress, for example Twenty Sixteen or the one that you've just indicated, it contain a lot of tools that actually I don't need. So the point is that I should ignore all the function that are already present on wordpress? and what about if I want to use bootstrap or fontawesome? Should I have only to replace the default css?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. If you are starting with wordpress, find template which is mostly what you want and modify it. The Twenty Sixteen is quite overloaded. I've also used bones template - quite blank one http://themble.com/bones/ Try to imagine what elements you want and find proper template ex. font awesome, bootstrap - try: http://strappress.com

Answer (score 1):

Marco if you want to just migrate the site into wordpress and don't want to use wordpress to process any data and display it for you then migration is not difficult.

just start with any blank site ( I would start with underscores available at http://underscores.me/  ) and then just keep the index.php, functions.php and style.css to start with and then add components as and when required.

actually functions.php is not mandatory to get your WP site up and running but you can enqueue your JS and CSS files here

the topic is a very detailed one but if you need further assistance then do lemme know

I will strongly advise you to read Theme Handbook on Wordpress.org site

Hope this helps

Take care and Happy coding